# jsf timestamp user inputs from different time zones

Tags: jsf, timezone, timestamp

I have a DB in GMT+1 (Germany) where a lot of timestamps are stored (dueTos and so on).

When a user from england now accesses the website and changes a timestamp.

but when he inputs e.g. 10.10.2016 10:00, of course not 10:00am should be stored in the db but 09:00 (the "timezone-corrected" time).

is there any way to achieve this?

I found articles which say it cannot be done in JSF, only with JS what I want to avoid. is there any solution to make the timezone-correction secure and relilable?

many thanks!

Comment: This is not related to JSF. A general thumb of rule : store date / time into your target database using a standard time zone like UTC (or GMT. UTC is  however, preferred over GMT in general) and convert it into a time zone of your interest, when it is fetched from the database i.e. when it is to be displayed for end-users.

Comment: How the reading and "converting" it to the specific timezone is known. But how about secure _storing_ the users date imput? convert it with javascript and passing it to the bean? seems too risky for me...

Comment: How do you convert an end-user's input which is in the form of a string, when an HTTP request is made by an end-user? You use converters in frameworks like JSF to convert a user input from a string (i.e a submitted value) to an appropriate Java type - here the converted value will be an appropriate date / time type of the API you are using to deal with date / time. You do not have to do anything with JavaScript here.